# Can't make background images fade in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used this code before for various other ideas but I've never done a fadein outside of animate so I wanted the images to fadein as they get changed, is it possible in this code? Or will i have to find another method? The spot where you see the fadein is where I currently have it but the fade in doesn't seem work. I've tried matching the time with interval with no luck as well.

```
$(function () { // DOCUMENT ready shorthand
    var cnt=0, bg;
    var $body = $('body');
    var arr = ['images/01.jpg','images/02.jpg','images/03.jpg','images/04.jpg','images/05.jpg','images/06.jpg','images/07.jpg'];

    var bgrotater = setInterval(function() {
        if (cnt==7) cnt=0;
        bg = 'url("' + arr[cnt] + '")';
        cnt++;
        $body.css('background-image', bg).fadeIn('fast');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: you are trying to fade in `<body>` but it is always visible in your code after the first time it fades in

Comment: How can you fadein something which is already visible..? or are you planning to hide `<body>` itself..?!

Comment: No I wanted a fadein transition effect for the image will come up next
Sorry that I suck, I'm new to javascript still.

Comment: http://chocobento.x10.mx/clients/Client_01_REDESIGN/home/
Here's the site where I'm testing this on.You can see the images change but there is no transition effect.

Comment: Guys I fixed it!
I added a transition in CSS body and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody has this issue in the future, so what you do is add the transition in the CSS like so.
Also notice the part where it says transition.

```
body {
font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #666;
background-image: url(images/01.jpg);
background-size: 100% 150%;
background-attachment:fixed;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #FFF;
transition: background 1.5s linear;
```

}

Comment: You can also simulate a background by adding a div on the body with `position:absolute;top:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;right:0px;z-index:-1;background:url('yourbg.png');`. Then you can use JQuery to fade in and out.

Comment: Yea I was about to that when I remembered about the transition effect.
But its less code this way so I stuck with this one but thanks for the answer :D